# How to find the next `n` files and `n+1`-th file for each file listed by `ls -1`

Tags: linux, bash

In a directory, for each file listed by `ls -1 .` in the default order which is the lexicographic order, I want to do the following

1. find the next `n` files starting from and including the file, putting them into an array named `train`, and copy them into a subdirectory `tmp`.
2. find the `n+1`-th file, putting it into a variable named `test`
3. perform some operation on `train`, `test`, and `tmp`. Remove files in `tmp`.

`train` and `test` are reused, and supposed to be overwritten for each file listed by `ls`.

`tmp` is supposed to be empty right before starting the above steps for each file listed by `ls`.

The three steps are performed on each file except the last `n` files listed by `ls`, because there is no `n+1`-th file starting from each of them.

I wonder how to implement the above in bash? Thanks.

**For example**,

suppose `n` is 2, and the files listed by `ls` in the current directory are:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

for `a`, I will find `a` and `b` and put them into array `train` and copy them into dir `tmp`, and find `c` and put it in   variable `test`. Then perform some operation on `train`, `test` and `tmp`. Finally, empty dir `tmp`.

for `b`, I will find `b` and `c`, and put them into array `train` by overwriting it,  and copy them into dir `tmp`, and find `d` and put it in   variable `test` by overwriting it. Then perform some operation on `train`, `test` and `tmp`. Finally, empty dir `tmp`.

Then the above is performed on `c` and `d`, but not on `e` and `f`, because `n`=2.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you are dividing a set of samples into training and test sets, random order would probably be more useful than just dividing a sorted list; that way you don't have to worry that adjacent samples are more similar than distant samples (as they often will be, if the input is some sort of human-controlled process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that doesn't actually copy or delete anything,

```
#!/bin/bash    
n=3
files=( $(ls -1) )  # Store list of files in array variable "files"
limit=$(( ${#files[*]} - $n - 1 ))  # All but last n+1 files.

echo mkdir -pv tmp

for i in $(seq 0 $limit)
do
  j=$(( $i + $n ))  # I put the index in a separate variable for clarity.
  test=${files[$j]}
  train=(${files[@]:$i:$n})
  echo cp -v ${train[*]} tmp/
  echo do_something $test, ${train[*]},  tmp/
  echo rm -vf tmp/*
done
```

References...

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq

Comment: [Don't parse ls!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Use glob. In this case, it would be `files=(*)`

Comment: And prefer `"${train[@]}" to ${train[*]}. In general, always quote variable expansions.

Comment: @rici: why "prefer `${train[@]}` to `${train[*]}`? How about `${#files[*]}`?

Comment: @tim: the quoting is important. `"${train[@]}"` works if some array element includes whitespace. Or is empty. Or is `*`. Iow, the same reason you should always quote a variable expansion. I might not quote `${#...` expansions but it certainly doesn't hurt.